# firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential Token mismatch

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I try to use Firebase Authentication to sign in a user by sending an SMS message to the user's phone. After entered phone number it shows Token mismatch

Here is my code:

```
await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
    verificationCompleted: (credential) async {
     ...
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
     ...
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
     ...
    },
    // called when the SMS code is sent
    codeSent: (verificationId, resendToken) {
     ...
    }
 );
```